# How to use LinkedIn API in iPhone SDK?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, linkedin-api

I want to use the [LinkedIn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LinkedIn) API in my project, but I haven't found any good tutorials about using LinkedIn API. How to use LinkedIn API?

"A beginners guide/introduction" of "basic concepts" would be helpful.

OK, after googleing around I went to this link [LinkedInAPI](http://developer.linkedin.com/community/apis).

I filled in the form but I am unable to understand what the "Integration URL" (Example URL where the integration will go live.)

Because I want to use LinkedIn in native iPhone application not on any website?

So after getting keys how do I use those keys and how do I authenticate user and get some profile info,post status like all the things?

I know for authentication there is an Objective-C wrapper `MPOAuthMobile`. I have also downloaded that but unable to understand. What this cumbersome API uses?

Comment: if nobody knows how to use it then why my question is downvoted?

Comment: +1 I don't know why it was downvoted either, but you should take care to format and spellcheck your questions.

Comment: I'm going to guess that you got down voted because the "please explain everything in detail" is a bit irritating. It smacks of "please write my app for me". Just say "a beginners guide/introduction" of "basic concepts" instead.

Comment: @TechZen do you know how to use linkedin api

Comment: @TechZen, yes, please write this app for me would be better suited to SuperUser :)

Comment: Have you tried asking specific question about how to use the API on the [LinkedIn API discussion forum](http://developer.linkedin.com/community/apis?view=discussions)?

Comment: Have you completed LinkedIn? I have completed Authentication Part but i have got this Message please let me know if you have got idea:
"You have successfully authorised [AppName].Please return to your application and enter following security code to grant access: 61592 " please help me what should i do?

Comment: @iosRider ohh... Same Message I got for my Facebook Sharing app in ios using FBGraph API. I searched on Google and also posted my query on some forums but didn't got its solution from anyone. :(
 If you got its solution please let me know what is that.
Thanks In Advance

Comment: Is there any Swift version of a tutorial these days? I'm using Swift but can't find a good tutorial for the LinkedIn SDK in iOS with Swift.

Answer (score 14):

I haven't been able to find a stable library/code-example that helped me get access to the LinkedIn api from a native iOS application.

That´s why I created this small library and published it at github: https://github.com/jeyben/IOSLinkedInAPI

The library is also available as a cocoapod if you are interested:
http://cocoapods.org/?q=IOSLinkedInAPI

IOSLinkedInAPI uses OAuth2 and helps you get an accessToken which is needed to actually call the LinkedIn Rest API.

Comment: Great library! Just what I needed. Thanks a lot. Btw I have a small issue. Say I run the app and grant access to it first time. How do I detect if the user is already authenticated or not when the app is run for the second time?

Comment: My immediate suggestion is to store the accesstoken and try to access linkedin on the users behalf. If it fails, then start the authorization process again.

Comment: Thanks. Will give it a try. Are you expanding this library to do API calls as well?

Comment: Hmmm. Currently I am not on a project which uses this library so on the short run no - *but* as it is opensource I would love if people would contribute and implement it.

Comment: Okay, good to know. I'd love to help out but I'm fairly inexperienced in working with APIs like these. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: @jeyben ur library works great...however, for ARC projects Json Kit isnt supproted...so stuck with that...!

Comment: @jeyben i really liked your code in that it was modern with oauth2 and used updated libraries like AFNetworking. BUT I'm totally stuck once I have the access token trying to actually make the api calls. Can you offer some help? Every example i see uses OAuthConsumer with no explanation or anything and builds a OAMutableRequest. Yours is much cleaner using AF and I already have the token. I'd hate to rewrite from step 1 with OA when I'm already all the way to the point of having an access token. Please help, thanks!

Comment: @jeyben can you please explain how to get user email address from your library

Comment: @jeyben : Great work saved my time thanks alot. but i need email address of user how do i get it?

Comment: @mychar : could u able to find out getting email address using this library?

Comment: @Mark13: -try this one(void)requestMeWithToken:(NSString *)accessToken {
    [self.client GET:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,maiden-name,email-address,location,date-of-birth,formatted-name,picture-url)?oauth2_access_token=%@&format=json", accessToken] parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSDictionary *result) {
        //NSLog(@"current user %@", result);
    }        failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"failed to fetch current user %@", error);
    }];
}

Comment: @Mark13 : if you find share a post via this library please help me.im still struggle in sharing part

Comment: @mychar : I tried ur suggestion but still am not getting the email though getting an error :  Authorization failed in didtapconnection Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)" UserInfo=0x7a957850 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorizedialog/submit, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorizedialog/submit}

Comment: @mychar : Regarding Sharing on LinkedIn have u tried this https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/linkedin-share ?

Comment: Nope I haven't. Is it any good? Do you know if it uses OAuth 2 as linkedIn emphasises?

Comment: Hii i got error #import "AFHTTPRequestOperation.h"
 not found