# LinkedIn add Events API

Tags: iphone, events, social-networking, linkedin-api

I need to add, through API, some events on LinkedIn.

Can anyone recommend me how to do this?

**UPDATE:** I want to use this on iPhone side.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, this might help you: http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/inauth-inevent-and-inui

Based on the fact you are an iPhone developer, you might be interested in:
http://developer.linkedin.com/thread/3035

http://github.com/ResultsDirect/LinkedIn-iPhone

[How to use LinkedIn API in iPhone SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346698/how-to-use-linkedin-api-in-iphone-sdk)

Answer (score 1):

There is no API available to add events to LinkedIn at this time.

Comment: I wonder if using Twitter to push #linkedin tweets would work :D

Comment: Assuming you've tied your twitter account into LinkedIn, how would pushing a tweet that gets posted to your LinkedIn stream create a new event?

Comment: When I post a #in or #linkedin tag inside a tweet, it pushes an event into Linked-in, but if I remember well it required my explicit consent, and is probably not what the poster is looking for.

Comment: I think you are confusing the term 'event' here. Those tweets that get pushed are called network updates. You can indeed post network updates, shares, jobs, etc to LinkedIn via the API. The original question was related to posting events to LinkedIn, meaning, I think, actual events like the following: http://events.linkedin.com/DreamForce-11/pub/534760

Comment: I understand your meaning, and your acception seems right to me. +1 for you :D