# Implement Linkedin feeds in iOS

Tags: ios, linkedin-api, implementation

I am new in iOS development and i want to add linkedin login in my app.I used some APIs to get login. but now i want to show feeds. please help me to solve this problem.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Do the 3-4 year old examples work? LinkedIn's login API likely hasn't changed much in that time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use LinkedIn API in iPhone SDK?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346698/how-to-use-linkedin-api-in-iphone-sdk)

Answer (score 3):

Recent code is here 2015:[Click herer Go to GitHub Link](https://github.com/jeyben/IOSLinkedInAPI)

You need to use a Library OAutho for integrating with user linkedin account and after login user can post a status to their linkedin account.First of all ,you have to download Library from https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/libraries-and-tools. Now you have to drag and drop OAuthLoginView,ASIHTTP and OAuthStarterKit folder in Project Navigator of Xcode.For Removing Linking error in xcode ,you have to add -all_load,-ObjC and -lc++ flag.

Comment: your trick is worked for me.  but how can we show  feeds/ news of linkedin app?